# Installed pyjokes but receiving "No module named 'pyjokes' error"

Tags: python

I am creating create a random joke generator using Python’s random
module. I have installed the py.jokes module using pip3 and it confirmed the following:

"Requirement already satisfied: pyjokes in c:\users\rasig\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.6.0)"

[image: Command Prompt]

Below is my code:

```
import pyjokes

joke = pyjoke.get.joke(language="en", category="neutral")

print(joke)
```

But when I run this code, I am receiving the following error:

[image: Error]

Can you please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Once the typos are resolved (`pyjoke` should be `pyjokes` in line 3; `get.joke()` should be `get_joke()` in the same line) I cannot reproduce this in [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/VelvetyVividStaff#main.py). Voting to close as typo/not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @esqew but still receiving the same error :-(

Comment: import pyjokes

joke = pyjokes.get_joke(language="en", category="neutral")

print(joke)

Comment: Make sure you are using the right python interprerter. You have installed pyjokes for pip3, are you using python3 as well? I just ran your code Rusty and works fine for me. There is something wrong with your enviroment.

Comment: I am using python3 and I amd doing the editing in Idle Adilius. Is that correct? This is so strange. I used the Command Prompt to install pyjokes - Is that the correct way as well?